# How to inspect if javascript/jquery is loaded in the DOM?

Tags: javascript

no examples this time. I am a bit new to javascript. What is the best option to inspect if a certain javascript is loaded in the DOM? Let's say now I applied colourbox to my site, but still its not working, so what I want to see if it is a problem with javascript or somewhere else.

Also, what is the best tool to inspect on a certain javascript online. Let's say I want to do something similar to: http://muthemes.com/yield/ - a javascript slider with borders from left and right, that starts with text "Advertising projects, graphic design jobs, architecture assignments". I really do not understand which script is loaded for this. Can you please share some wisdom with me in order not to create such post's in the future. Thanks! I will appreciate very much.

Comment: for debug - manually add `alert` or `console.log` in the end of library file.

Comment: can you give a certain "alert" sample?

Comment: `alert('Wohoo, i am being loaded!');`

Answer (score 1):

for Firefox: [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/). Chrome, Opera and IE have similar build-in functions (just press F12 / search for "developer console" on google).

This tools provide a console, detailed error-messages, debugging tools, dom- and css-inspectors and a lot of other useful stuff to make inspectinig and debugging a website very easy.

just install/open and play around to get used to this tools. they're almost self-explaining. For more information, there are a lot of [wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)s and good tutorials out there in the www - just ask google for help.